# Netbeans Scaling on 4K Screen

Tags: java, netbeans, scaling, hidpi

I got a new 4K Monitor and everything looks amazing but coding with NetBeans is difficult. The controls are very small and a java frame looks very small.

I've seen some Stackoverflow posts about this problem and they said I should add a line in the preferences file so that hi-dpi mode is disabled but my java frame is still small.

Comment: Use `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2.5` instead: https://superuser.com/a/1194728/465745

Comment: @ron190, thanks a lot. This worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those who land here like me in 2019.

Currently using Apache Netbeans 11 in a 4k monitor and changing the `dpiaware` option has no effect for me.

What worked is adding the option `-J-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2.5` to the file `netbeans.conf` just before `-J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true`.

The indicted piece of the file:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-XX:+UseStringDeduplication -J-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true -J-Xss2m  -J-Djdk.gtk.version=2.2 -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2.5 -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dplugin.manager.check.updates=false -J-Dnetbeans.extbrowser.manual_chrome_plugin_install=yes -J--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-modules=jdk.jshell -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.javadoc/com.sun.tools.javadoc.main=ALL-UNNAMED -J-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions"
```

Thanks to [ron190](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073804/ron190) that help us pointing this out:

> Use -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2.5 instead: superuser.com/a/1194728/465745

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much, it's exaclty what was working for me. Everything else failed.

Comment: It seems to ignore the fractional part. I tried 1.5 and it looked the same as one. Once I tried 2 or bigger the scaling changed. I was hoping for 1.5 but 2.0 is better than 1.0 for me.

Comment: Anyone landing here in 2021: Neither solution is working for me with Netbeans 12.3 in Windows 10. If you have a solution it would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 8):

For those who land here in 2021.

I am using Netbeans 12.4 on Windows 10 and the solutions mentioned here did nothing for me.

What did work was setting the high DPI settings in Compatibility Mode like so:

[image]

Big thanks to the following post that set me on the right path, it offers a powershell command to do this automatically for all java exes: https://superuser.com/a/1276743/648833

Comment: Only answer that worked for me on 12.2 in 2021 on Windows 11. Text renders a little blurry this way, but it's better than it being so small I can't read it at all.

Comment: Excellent Solution.... The accepted answer did not work for me.

Comment: This is the appropriate solution for 2022. I had the same problem and this is what saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try to edit `NETBEAN_HOME\etc\netbeans.conf` and set `-J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware` from true to **false**.

```
-J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux, other than trying to set

```
-J-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2
```

make sure that you are using jdk 11+, as jdk 8 does not seems to pick up that config

Answer (score 0):

I am on windows and using ney beans 8.2 with JDK 8. None of the above approaches works for me.

For me, the best route is to add `--fontsize 32` at the end of the `netbeans_default_options` variable:

[image]

You can use whatever font size you like. Remember to change the editor font size to a larger value at 1st boot. The code navigation bar beneath the editor area looks strange, but enough for me.

[image]